# xhr.statusが200番台かどうかのコード

Tags: javascript

```
  if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300)  // http status between 200 to 299 are all successful
```

このようなjavascriptのコードがあるのですが、これはstatusが200しかtrueにならないと思うのですが、どういうことでしょうか？

Comment: あなたが書かれれているように、その判定では、`xhr.status`が200ちょうどの時にしか条件が成立しません。おそらく「単なる書き間違い」でしょう。200番台の終了コードは200以外はあまり使用されないので、デバッグが不十分なのだと思われます。そのレベルの書き間違いがあるようだと、コメントがあてになるかどうかも怪しいので、どういった場面でその判定をしているのかわからないと「どういうこと」(本来どうあるべき)かを答えるのは難しいですね。

Comment: コメントアウトの通りだとすると`xhr.status == 200 && `が後で記載されたものではないでしょうか？元々300未満を見ていたけど、試験的に200のみにしたらうまくいったからそのままだったとか？